# Android VOLLEY enviar json y recibir json en response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Buenas, lo que estoy intentando realizar es enviar un json desde Android con Volley a un php que tengo en mi servidor, dentro del php realizo algunas consultas y necesito que me devuelva otro json (response) para trabajar con dichos datos. Aclaro que ese PHP funciona bien con otra APP que uso httpPost, pero como esta deprecated estoy actualizando la APP utilizando VOLLEY

EL problema que tengo es que no ingresa al código, con el debug me doy cuenta que de la primera línea

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL,
                        jsonParams,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Salta directamente a la siguiente línea fuera de esta función quizás tengo algo mal en los parámetros o en la declaración, les dejo el código

```
**** Desde esta primera linea salta directamente a requestQueue.add(postRequest); sin entrar *****


JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL,
    jsonParams,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject Obj = response;
                JSONArray jarray = Obj.getJSONArray("usu");
                if (jarray.length() <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SIN REGISTROS PARA ACTUALIZAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object1 = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String variable = object1.getString("variable");
                        String variable2 = object1.getString("variable2");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }) {

    };
    *** salta directamente a esta línea ****
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SettingsActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(postRequest); 
    **** En la línea anterior me muestra lo siguiente debugeando: RequestQueue: RequestQueue@5107 postRequest: "[] www.url.com/php/ejemplo.php 0xb7f7dc44 NORMAL null"

    }else{
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El Servicior y/o el Usuario no pueden estar vacíos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();
    }

    }
});
}
```

GRACIAS !!!

Comment: Al actualizar elSDK se soluciona el asunto con lo de omitir el metodo onResponse.

Answer (score 3):

Bueno chicos al fin lo resolví, no pregunten porque ni como, son esos misterios del a informática jajaja, creo no haber modificado nada e igual salió andando y funciona, se los dejo por si a alguién le interesa. Lo que hace este botón es tomar el usuario y el servidor que están en inputs de la activity, los manda como parámetros json a un php. Ese php hace un select de una tabla según el usuario y me devuelve también un json que lo tomo, lo proceso y lo muestro en un TOAST a modo de ejemplo para verificar si llegaban. Lo que ven ahí de MCrypt() es para encriptar los datos, SALUDOS

Les dejo el código por si les sirve

```
btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // por si el usuario los cambio los vuelvo a referenciar
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SettingsActivity.this);
                usuario_celu = et_usuario_celu.getText().toString();
                servidor_celu = et_servidor_celu.getText().toString();
                if (!(servidor_celu == null || servidor_celu.equals("") || usuario_celu == null || usuario_celu.equals(""))){
                    mcrypt = new MCrypt();
                    try {
                        usuario_celu_e = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt( usuario_celu));
                        servidor_celu_e = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt( servidor_celu));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String URL = servidor_celu.trim() + Globales.CREAR_RELACION;
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
                    dialog.setMessage("Registrando Usuario...");
                    dialog.show();


                    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonParams.put("username", usuario_celu_e);
                        jsonParams.put("server", servidor_celu_e);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL,
                            jsonParams,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject Obj = response;
                                        JSONArray jarray = Obj.getJSONArray("usu");
                                        if (jarray.length() <= 0) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SIN REGISTROS PARA ACTUALIZAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject object1 = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                                String empresa_e = object1.getString("empresa");
                                                String sucursal_e = object1.getString("sucursal");
                                                String passw_e = object1.getString("password");
                                                String servidor_e = object1.getString("servidor");

                                                mcrypt = new MCrypt();
                                                try {
                                                    String empresa =  new String(mcrypt.decrypt(empresa_e));
                                                    String sucursal = new String(mcrypt.decrypt(sucursal_e));
                                                    String passw =    new String(mcrypt.decrypt(passw_e));
                                                    String servidor = new String(mcrypt.decrypt(servidor_e));
                                                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DATOS: " + empresa + " | " + sucursal + " | " + passw + " | " + servidor , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                    toast2.show();
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }) {

                    };

                    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
                }else{
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El Servicior y/o el Usuario no pueden estar vacíos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tiene sentido que saltee todo el código del segundo bloque ya que la llamada no se hace inmediatamente sino cuando volley recibe la respuesta.

En el momento en que llamas `requestQueue.add(postRequest)`  volley encola esa solicitud y la ejecuta asincrónicamente, por lo tanto todo el código de `onResponse` se va a ejecutar después de esa llamada, cuando volley envíe la solicitud y reciba el resultado.

Para poder hacer el debug te sugiero poner un breakpoint en la primera linea de `onResponse` y `onErrorResponse` de esa manera detendrá el hilo cuando recibas la respuesta de la llamada.

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo pense a eso pero lo raro es que la APP se cierra !!! sin largar ningún tipo de error y en el debugestoy con F8 osea que al menos debería pasar por ahí, por ejemplo en los Asynctask pasa con F8 pero en este caso es como que ahí termino, obviamente hay un error porque la APP se cierra, pero no me muestra ningún error